# how to set htaccess to only allow www and dev

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a server and I'm trying to setup a dev and production environment but when the production server is live is allowing any random subdomain on the request url like:

```
abc.example.com
```

and I wanna to allow only www and dev, this is my .htaccess settings:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to achieve that and is my htaccess ok?

Comment: You should not place your production and your development environment on the same system!

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

apache variable %{REQUEST_SCHEME} passes http or https according to your request.